# Call batch script into Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have simple batch .bat script which copies data from one location to other location and batch script does not have any exit codes. It is just a .bat file with copy command to copy files. I want to call .bat script into power shell script and fail power shell script if .bat failed. here is the my sample code of power shell script.

```
$BatchScriptLocation="\\SomeNetworkServer\Folder"
$BatchScriptName="Test.bat"   ---simple batch script with no exit codes.

$RunBat = Start-Process -FilePath $BatchScriptLocation\$BatchScriptName -Wait -passthru;$a.ExitCode

If ($RunBat -eq 0) 
{
echo "Batch script execution success"
exit 0
}
else
{
echo "Batch script execution failed"
exit 1
}
```

Comment: Why do you run a `.bat` script from PoSh?  Moreover, `$RunBat` is an object  of `System.Diagnostics.Process` type; check `$RunBat.ExitCode -eq 0` as  `$RunBat -eq 0` is always false and never true. Furthermore,  `$RunBat.ExitCode` is 0 or 1 based on errorlevel of the last command in your `Test.bat` script .For instance, (on the assumption that) the `Test.bat` script contains only `copy` commands and the last one fails then  `$RunBat.ExitCode`  is 1 but if all `copy`s fail _except_ the last (successful) one then `$RunBat.ExitCode`  is 0. My final advice: do the job in the PowerShell  script.

Comment: bat script written by different team and our application won't allow to run bat scripts. so we need to use their bat script through powershell. I need to bring batch script status into IF statement and drive the powershell process.